# requesting data indefinitely in curl

Tags: bash, curl, download

I have 200MB file to download. I don't want to download it directly by passing URL to cURL (because my college blocks requests with more than 150MB).
So, I can download data by 10MB chunks, by passing range parameters to cURL. But I don't know how many 10MB chunks to download. Is there a way in cURL so that I can download data indefinitely. Something more like

while(next byte present)
download byte;

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

command line curl lets you specify a range to download, so for your 150meg max, you'd do something like

```
curl http://example.com/200_meg_file -r 0-104857600 > the_file
curl http://example.com/200_meg_file -r 104857601-209715200  >> the_file
```

and so on until the entire thing's downloaded, grabbing 100meg chunks at a time and appending each chunk to the local copy.

Answer (score 1):

Curl already has the ability to resume a download. Just run like this:

```
$> curl -C - $url -o $output_file
```

Of course this won't figure out when to stop, per se. However it would be pretty easy to write a wrapper. Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
url="http://someurl/somefile"
out="outfile"

touch "$out"
last_size=-1
while [ "`du -b $out | sed 's/\W.*//'`" -ne "$last_size" ]; do
    curl -C - "$url" -o "$out"
    last_size=`du -b $out | sed 's/\W.*//'`
done
```

I should note that curl outputs a fun looking error:

```
curl: (18) transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
```

However I tested this on a rather large ISO file, and the md5 still matched up even though the above error was shown.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But using -C, cURL is requesting the whole file where my school firewall is blocking it :(

Comment: Are you saying that the school sees the file size being returned from the server and stops it before it can even begin?

Comment: sorry for the late reply but yes